# Play JSON Reads Combinator Syntax: access raw JsValue?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play's `Reads` combinator syntax to read quite a huge JSON structure. This works well, except for one field:

```
implicit val reads: Reads[SomeEntity] = (
    (__ \ "name").read[String] and
    // a lot more to read, omitted...
    ...  and
    (__ \ "settings").read[Seq[Setting]](settingsReads(<name here>))
)(...)
```

As you can see above, the custom `Reads[Setting]` (here: `settingsReads`) needs the `name` field of the json structure - the same name that is read on line 2. But how could I access it? It could be done manually using `(JsValue \ "name").as[String]`, but therefore the "raw" `JsValue` would be required which is not the case when using the combinator syntax. Or am I wrong? Is there an easier approach?

**edit:** TL;DR: I want to pass the *name*-String of the entity to the settingsReads method.

Comment: Yes, you right. You can use `name` value without JsValue in Reads. Can you refine your question with Json example and describe how you want use `name` value.

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear enough. What I want to do is to pass the _name_-String to the reads that is needed to get the settings. In other words: method call on line 5 needs String from line 2. The definition of `settingsReads` is `def settingsReads(name: String): Reads[Setting]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Reads[SomeEntity]:

```
implicit val reads: Reads[SomeEntity] = (
    (__ \ "name").read[String] and
    // a lot more to read, omitted...
    ...  and
    (__ \ "name").read[String].flatMap(name => 
     (__ \ "settings").read[Seq[Setting]](settingsReads(name))
    )
)(...)
```